# Category products only properly reindex when save product in admin

Tags: magento2, reindex

I've been importing products into Magento using magmi. Some products, about 200 out of 1500, are not being indexed properly. I have a root category called Tires which is anchor and then sub-categories that are anchors that contain products.

Some, not all, of the products are not being associated with the root Tires category after I run the reindexer. They only get associated after I go into the admin and save the product.

I've compared products that work and products that don't and can't find any difference.

Has anyone run into this problem before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to a bug in Magento. They limit the product/category associations to 500 products I guess so that's why some seemed to randomly not appear in the layered navigation

Comment: I am getting same issue with magento 2.1. Did you get any solution for this issue ?